# Make items push down others if they become bigger on a ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm Looking for a way to make items push others if they become bigger as you would do using CSS with Divs. I know it's not the best explanation but in other words. " Make items adjustable to the content size you can see this on Bio, and The green Tags shown on the image below. I would like to listen to some guidance that could come handy.

Can i Use TableViewCell for this????

[image]

I want to reproduce something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use table view and use custom cell. When a new tag is added or tag is removed, call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)`, this would call the HeightForRowAtIndex and cellForRowAtIndexPath. Based on the new set of values, provide the header and contents. You can specify the animation in reloadRowsAtIndexPath to make it look as if the cell is expanding, without affecting other cells.